# Q function equality

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

While solving a Neyman-Pearson Detection problem I need to solve this equation:

$$Q\left ( \frac{\gamma^{'}-\mu_0}{d/\sqrt2}\right )=1-Q\left (\frac{\gamma^{'}-\mu_1}{d/\sqrt2}\right )$$

With $Q(x)$ being the tail probability of the standard normal distribution defined as follows:
$$Q(x) = \int_x^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\right)d\lambda$$

I don't know how to proceed. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: i have to solve it for $\gamma^{'}$

Comment: When $\mu_0=\mu_1$, there is no closed-form solution.  However, $Q$ is differentiable, so you may apply any root-finding software you like.

Comment: I forgot to say that $\mu_1 > \mu_0$

Comment: Is this true $1-Q(x) = Q(-x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true that $1-Q(x) = Q(-x)$ for all $x$. Sketch the standard normal pdf and mark on it the areas corresponding to $Q(x)$ and $Q(-x)$ to get some intuition as to why this is so. *Then,* you can write out a formal proof with integrals etc. if your instructor insists that you
use the definition of $Q(x)$ as an integral

Using the above result, the solution to your problem is trivial. $\gamma$
must be such that 
$$\gamma - \mu_0 = -(\gamma - \mu_1) \implies \gamma = \frac{\mu_0 + \mu_1}{2}.$$ 
Note that the calculation does not make any assumption about which
of $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$ is larger; indeed, it gives the correct
answer even when  $\mu_0 = \mu_1$ (in contradiction of @whuber's
claim that there is no closed-form solution when  $\mu_0 = \mu_1$).

---

**Comment:** Calculations such as these are very common in digital communications textbooks where either a $0$ or a $1$ is transmitted
over a channel that adds Gaussian noise to the signal being
transmitted. The output of a receiver is a *conditionally* normal
random variable $X$ whose conditional means are $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$
respectively (with $\mu_1 > \mu_0$, say) and common variance
$\sigma^2$. The receiver decides that a $1$ was transmitted if
$X > \gamma$ and that a $0$ was transmitted if $X < \gamma$. It
follows readily that $P_{e,0}$, the probability of error when
a $0$ has been transmitted, is given by
$$P_{e,0} = P\{X > \gamma\mid 0 ~ \text{transmitted}\}
= Q\left(\frac{\gamma-\mu_0}{\sigma}\right)$$
while $P_{e,1}$, the probability of error when
a $1$ has been transmitted, is given by
$$P_{e,1} = P\{X < \gamma\mid 1 ~ \text{transmitted}\}
= \Phi\left(\frac{\gamma-\mu_1}{\sigma}\right)
= 1 -Q\left(\frac{\gamma-\mu_1}{\sigma}\right).$$
The threshold $\gamma$ that forces $P_{e,0}$ to equal $P_{e,0}$ 
is called the *equalizer* threshold. In this simple problem,
the equalizer threshold is also the *minimax* threshold; the 
threshold that minimizes $\max \{P_{e,0}, P_{e,0}\}$. For more
on such matters, see Chapter 5.3 of M.B.Pursley, *Introduction
to Digital Communications,* Pearson Prentice-Hall, 2005.